# How to improve the Q & A experience for lengthy posts

Tags: discussion

I found when doing the [stone steps post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-build-stone-steps) that the format of Stack Exchange is not well suited for a series of questions on the same topic.  Specifically:

- questions have to have a certain length and cannot duplicate existing.  I have to find a way to re-ask the same question for each post
- it would be nice if there was the option to link to other questions in the series instead of having to do it manually
- if I make one huge post then it is slow to load due to graphic content but multiple posts make it difficult to present a coherent flow of information
- I'm absolutely mortified that this forum looks like gardening.kevinsky.com. If this is my five minutes of fame I'll wear a paper bag

This is a great experiment to bring traffic to the site and increase the number of questions per day.  I thank you all for your patience and hope the public finds the content to be useful.

Comment: just a warning for future: It might be better to pace the posts (perhaps one/two per day) instead of flooding. In addition to covering the front page, a (major) disadvantage for you is that people will see a series of Q&A by you and vote for them (because that's the only thing there). However, the automatic scripts in the system will think that they're serially upvoting you fraudulently (this was implemented to overcome co-workers and fans from artificially inflating a person's rep). In this case, though legitimate, might trip the script and it will remove _all_ votes that they've cast for you

Comment: It would be nice to have an area where a how-to series could be assembled and given the once over for editing before it is posted.  Is this possible?

Comment: @kevinsky chat + google docs is probably your best best on that front